# handle image error gracefully w/ SVG element & react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

I’m trying to load a placeholder image gracefully when the original image path/url is undefined or null.
I have a onError method that handles events of this type however the onError method I am using particularly takes in an HTMLImageElement . I would like the placeholder image to be of a SVG (imported from a S3 bucket and stored, then called to the application). How can I display an SVG element when my original image path is null or undefined?

[code in question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNtL2.png)

Comment: Please take the time to edit your post and copy and paste the code to be a part of your question. If you don't get the formatting right the first time, we'll help you with that. But an image of code, either linked or embeded, will lower the chance of getting an answer significantly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.